# Least squares approximation for a exponentially damped sinusoid

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, least-squares

I have a set of $N$ 2D points, namely ${(t_i,x_i)}^N_{i=1}$.
Those points should hold the equation: $x(t) = Ae^{{-\alpha}t}\sin({\omega}t+\phi)$,
Where A,$\alpha,\omega$ and $\phi$ are constants.
Since these points are gained from physical measurements, they include errors and does not hold the above equation.
As a result, I need to find the 'closest' function (of this form) to those points, specifically to find the above constants.
Is there a way to find such a function? (via an approximation of course)
maybe using the least-squares method? if so, how?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Omri

Comment: Can you joint to the question an example of data $(x_i,y_i)$ ( numerical, not graph). This is necessary to check and show a method of damped sinusoidal regression.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply and sorry for my late response, the scenario is that I have N 2D points of an oscillating rod along a time interval [0:t] and I want to extract it's natural frequency (assuming I know it's damping type, say under-damped).
since it's an equation of the form I've wrote above, can this be done using least squares method? if not, then how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can olny repeat my above comment. It is written what is necessay for me to answer.